# Notice : Array to String conversion in

Tags: php, html, array

Estou com um problema no seguinte código :

```
<select name="tipoPessoa" class="form-control">
    <?php 
        $tipos = array("Pessoa Fisica","Pessoa Juridica");
        $tipoSemEspaco = str_replace(" ","",$tipos);

        foreach ($tipos as $tipo):
        $esseEhOTipo = get_class($pessoa) == $tipoSemEspaco;
        $selecaoTipo = $esseEhOTipo ? "selected='selected'" : "";
    ?>
  // Linha 22 <option value="<?=$tipoSemEspaco?>" <?=$selecaoTipo?>>
                <?=$tipo?>
            </option>       

    <?php  endforeach ?>

</select>
```

Quando abro o console do navegador, ele me informa um Notice:

> Array To String conversion in line 22

Estou tentando atribuir no value do campo o valor sem os  espaços e esta dando este erro.

Answer (score 1):

O motivo do erro é porque `$tipoSemEspaco` é uma nova array, que é independente do `$tipos`.

Uma correção fácil:

Adicione o *index* no `foreach`:

```
foreach($tipos as $index => $tipo){ 
    /...
}
```

Então utilize ele para obter o respectivo `$tipoSemEspaco`:

```
<?=$tipoSemEspaco[$index]?>
```

No final:

```
<select name="tipoPessoa" class="form-control">
    <?php 
        $tipos = array("Pessoa Fisica","Pessoa Juridica");
        $tipoSemEspaco = str_replace(" ","",$tipos);

        foreach ($tipos as $index => $tipo):
        $esseEhOTipo = get_class($pessoa) == $tipoSemEspaco;
        $selecaoTipo = $esseEhOTipo ? "selected='selected'" : "";
    ?>
  // Linha 22 <option value="<?=$tipoSemEspaco[$index]?>" <?=$selecaoTipo?>>
                <?=$tipo?>
            </option>       

    <?php  endforeach ?>

</select>
```

---

Uma outra opção seria adicionar algo do tipo:

```
$tiposPessoasDisponiveis = [
   0 => ['TextoHumano' => 'Pessoa Fisica', 'ValorMaquina' => 'PessoaFisica'],
   1 => ['TextoHumano' => 'Pessoa Juridica', 'ValorMaquina' => 'PessoaJuridica'],
];
```

Já que são poucas opções e não tende a mudar isto frequentemente, NESTE CASO, isto poderia ser viável, então:

```
<select name="tipoPessoa" class="form-control">
        <?php 

            $tipos = [
                0 => ['TextoHumano' => 'Pessoa Fisica', 'ValorMaquina' => 'PessoaFisica'],
                1 => ['TextoHumano' => 'Pessoa Juridica', 'ValorMaquina' => 'PessoaJuridica'],
            ];

            foreach ($tipos as $tipo):
                $esseEhOTipo = get_class($pessoa) == $tipo['ValorMaquina'];
                $selecaoTipo = $esseEhOTipo ? "selected='selected'" : "";
                ?>
                <option value="<?=$tipo['ValorMaquina']?>" <?=$selecaoTipo?>>
                    <?=$tipo['TextoHumano']?>
                </option>

            <?php  endforeach ?>

</select>
```

---

**Pessoalmente não acho isso muito bom**, porque simplesmente torna confuso entender o que é cada coisa, são duas arrays distintas e que possui uma relação direta, isso é minha opinião, justamente para isto eu preferiria fazer:

```
<select name="tipoPessoa" class="form-control">
        <?php 

            $tiposPessoasDisponiveis = ['Pessoa Fisica', 'Pessoa Juridica'];

            foreach ($tiposPessoasDisponiveis as $tipoPessoa){

                $tipoSemEspacamento = str_replace(' ', '', $tipoPessoa);

                $estaSelecionado = get_class($pessoa) == $tipoSemEspacamento;

                $atributoOptionHTML = '';
                $atributoOptionHTML .= 'value = "'.$tipoSemEspacamento.'"';
                $atributoOptionHTML .= $estaSelecionado ? 'selected' : '';

                ?>
                <option <?= $atributoOptionHTML ?>>
                    <?= $tipoPessoa ?>
                </option>

            <?php  } ?>

</select>
```

Enfim, adicionar o `str_replace` dentro do `foreach`, dessa forma fica claro qual é o objetivo dele, renomeei as funções para que tentar presentar melhor as suas "funções", *ao meu ver*. **Mas, logicamente isto é totalmente opcional.**

Answer (score 0):

Sim, de fato você está tentando atribuir um array como valor, onde deveria ser string. Isso acontece porque nessa expressão:

```
$tipos = array("Pessoa Fisica","Pessoa Juridica");
$tipoSemEspaco = str_replace(" ","",$tipos);
```

Você está tentando substituir parte do array `$tipos`. A função que me pareceu mais adequada para sua operação é a [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). Seria algo como:

```
$tipos = array("Pessoa Fisica","Pessoa Juridica");
$tipoSemEspaco = implode(" ",$tipos);
```

E assim você teria de fato uma string na variável `$tipoSemEspaco`

Comment: O implode tem uma ideia totalmente diferente do `str_replace` neste caso, talvez o OP realmente queira isto, mas não me parece. O `str_replace` aparentemente foi feito para remover espaços, ou seja o `Pessoa Fisica` ir para `PessoaFisica`. Utilizar o `implode` ficará `Pessoa Fisica Pessoa Juridica`, numa mesma string, nem sequer faz jus ao nome de "semEspaco". Pelo contesto não parece ser isto, mas pode ser que seja isto que o OP queira, de qualquer forma.

Answer (score 0):

Está atribuindo um parâmetro do tipo array para uma função que deveria receber o tipo string.

Uma sugestão de correção:

```
<select name="tipoPessoa" class="form-control">
    <?php 
        $tipos = array("Pessoa Fisica","Pessoa Juridica");

        foreach ($tipos as $tipo):
        $tipoSemEspaco = str_replace(' ', '', $tipo);
        $esseEhOTipo = get_class($pessoa) == $tipoSemEspaco;
        $selecaoTipo = $esseEhOTipo ? "selected='selected'" : "";
    ?>
    <option value="<?=$tipoSemEspaco?>" <?=$selecaoTipo?>>
                <?=$tipo?>
            </option>       

    <?php  endforeach ?>

</select>
```

Nessa correção optei por ser menos invasivo possível, mantendo o seu código original.

<sub>*Me abstenho em comentar sobre outras questões.

O código acima deve resolver o problema principal.</sub>